# Error installing Homebrew on OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, homebrew

I'm attempting to install [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29), but I'm running into some issues. I listed the result below. How can I fix this problem?

```
$ ~ $ brew install wget
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/wget/wget-1.14.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/wget-1.14.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/wget/1.14 --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc --with-ssl=openssl --disable-iri
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... ./configure: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed:/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh build-aux/config.sub
./configure: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
./configure: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

Note: I uninstalled MacPorts beforehand and `brew doctor` works without a hitch.

**Solved**: I settled with an alternate installation method ("Untar anywhere") that I found on the [Homebrew wiki page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation).

What I ran: `mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew`

Comment: Possibly a red herring: but check the formula file: it mentions a configure error that may occur depending on your `awk` installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/bin/bash^M` is your clue. For some reason there's a DOS line-end character in what's being downloaded. This is probably an error in the formula, but if you're adventurous, you can `brew install dos2unix` and then run `dos2unix` on the folder in question.

Comment: I'm glad :) Maybe for posterity you could edit your question to say what you did to get it working?

Comment: Updated. I didn't get to try your method, but just relieved it worked out in the end. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Windows style end-of-line in Unix/Linux/Mac OS X. If you modified your Git core.autocrlf attribute before, then try:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Then reinstall Homebrew.